# What happens if I connect 24V to 5V push switch?

Tags: switches

In this circuit I am using a push button rated 5V.  I am planning to connect a voltage source having 24V.  What will happen?

---

Circuit diagram of the switch.

[image: Circuit diagram]

[Datasheet of switch](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/15/SPVR-1370981.pdf)

Partnumber: SPVR110102

Comment: Arc over? Wear out?

Comment: probably, it will heat up or burn depending on current flow over

Comment: The button likely won't survive.

Comment: It’s the load current that matters. Presume it’s for logic currents only.

Comment: I've never heard of switch _contacts_ that are rated for such low voltage. What exactly _is_ this "push button" that you are talking about? Is it something other than a simple, mechanical switch? Some kind of a snap-dome thing? Some assembly with a touch or pressure sensor and active electronics? Is it lighted? Maybe you could provide a link to a data sheet.

Comment: You understand what rated means for a component!  Nothing good happens when you operate a component beyond it's rated values.  The key here is the current through the pushbutton, so you should find it's data sheet.  Odds are that at 5V, it has an LED.

Comment: What will happen where? to the push button? to the load? to the source? Can we have datasheets?

Comment: Your numbers are unrealistic so any prediction of what will happen will also be unrealistic. More realistic would be a switch rated for 1 A while the lightbulb consumes 5 A. Then, depending on how the switch is constructed, the switch is likely to fail. It could fail **open** meaning, after closing the switch, it will fail (for example: a thin connection breaks) and be permanently open and the lamp cannot be switched on because the switch doesn't close anymore. The switch can also fail **closed** (for examples: the switch contacts fuse together) then the lamp wil stay on forever.

Comment: OK, you added a link to a switch. The specification of that switch is clear, it cannot handle more than 5 V and more than 1 mA. The switch is very likely to fail if you do exceed those ratings. As explained above, the switch can fail open or closed. It actually doesn't matter how it fails as you should not be using it like you suggest. Use a different switch or make sure the switch's ratings are not exceeded. Why are you asking for trouble?

Comment: Maybe you should better understand **maximum ratings**: The maximum rating is the voltage and current that are **guaranteed by the manufacturer** to be used with this device and will not result in **damage**. If you stay below those maximum values and the siwtch breaks anyway, you can ask the manufacturer for a replacement. However, if you do exceed the maximum ratings, break the switch and ask the manufacturer for a replacement, you might not get one as the manufacturer will say: "You exceeded the maximum ratings so it is your own fault that the switch breaks."

Comment: Buy one and give it a try. It may work for a while, or it may fail instantly.  Either way, you don’t want to be using this switch in these conditions.

Comment: (Re-opening question as the missing datasheet of the specific switch has been added. This information was provided by the OP as a new question, when it should have been added as an edit to this original question instead.)

Comment: Probably it will work fine for a while because 10 mA is a fairly low current. But nobody here on EESE can promise you anything because we didn't design the switch, don't have the part number or manufacturer or even a picture of the switch. So, you are on your own.

Comment: Normally, if you said you wanted to violate a switch's voltage rating by 5x and violate its current rating by 10x I would tell you that you were crazy. But in this case, I don't believe the ratings because 1mA is ridiculously small.

Answer (score 8):

> What will happen?

No one knows. Once you operate a part outside it's specified limits, the behavior is undefined.

Could work just fine, could explode or burn, could break after 10 operations, could be anything.

Any part is thoroughly tested and qualified INSIDE the boundaries of it's stated limits. No one tests or characterizes outside these limits, because you are NOT supposed to use it that way. Once you go there, you are entirely on your own.

Answer (score 2):

From datasheet:

Maximum ratings are: 1mA 5V DC. Contact resistance is 3Ω max.

You want 10mA at 24V.  You have exceeded current and voltage ratings.

Operation beyond ratings is undefined but odds are good switch will burn up.  Rated for 3µW and you will have 300µW.  Seems small and meaningless, but still 100x ratings.