# What will happen to the circuit and switch if I connect a 5V 1mA switch to 24V 10mA load and 24V 1A source?

Tags: switches

Circuit diagram of the switch.

[image: Circuit diagram]

[Datasheet of switch](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/15/SPVR-1370981.pdf)

Partnumber: SPVR110102

Comment: This information (schematic and datasheet link) should have been added into [the original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572667/what-happens-if-i-connect-24v-to-5v-push-switch) as an edit. In order to preserve the comments that were added *here* as well as the existing ones *there*, all in one place, I will merge the questions.